# Linq group by ID and then sum the ID itself (key)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, group-by, sum

I have two lists which are basically of the same class type like following:

```
   public class TransactionsTabResults
{
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string ItemImage { get; set; }

    public float ItemPrice { get; set; }

    public int PageViews { get; set; }

    public float AveragePrice { get; set; }

    public int TotalSoldItems { get; set; }

    public float TotalRevenuePerItem { get; set; }

}
```

The list #1 is the TransactionsData and it contains 250 items whose only initialized properties are: ItemID, Title and ItemPrice;

The ItemID itself repeats several times inside the first List. Now what I'm trying to achieve in second list(transactionsList) is following:

```
 var _transactionsList = TransactionsData.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(pr => new TransactionsTabResults {
                            ItemID = pr.Key,
                            Title = pr.Select(x => x.Title).FirstOrDefault(),
  // here goes total sales of the item => sum of the groupby function by ItemID
// here goes the average selling price => sum above divided by price of the item 
                            TotalRevenuePerItem= pr.Sum(y=>y.ItemPrice)
                        });
```

As you can see I'm trying to group all the items inside the list by ItemID and then sum the the key to get the amount of sales per item (if you guys understand what I'm trying to achieve) - the amount of times that the ID repeats itself is the amount of sales that item has...

Can someone help me out to figure this out?

Edit:  I need to get the key value (The parameter I'm grouping by the whole list) - value/amount of how many times ItemID repeats itself in #1 list...

Comment: @GiladGreen Okay I'll post and example data

Comment: @GiladGreen: If you have the price (per sale) and the number of sales, it's easy to generate the total and average by summing and averaging...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to "sum the IDs" - you just need the average of the prices, which you can get using the `Average` method. If you want the count, just call `Count()`:

```
AverageRevenuePerItem = pr.Average(y => y.ItemPrice),
TotalSalesPerItem = pr.Count()
```

Summing IDs - or performing any other kind of arithmetic with them - is always a bad idea. If they are generated in a monotonic order then comparing them (in terms of higher/lower for later/earlier) *can* be useful, but other than that you should treat them as values which can *only* be compared for equality.

Separately, I'd *strongly* advise you to revise your data model. Currently you've got a mixture of "this is a single sale" and "this is an aggregate of sales". That's just going to lead to confusion. Likewise it's not clear that you need a title in the transaction - that should be in a separate table/model describing the items. So I can see you having something like:

```
Item:
  Id
  Title

Transaction:
  ItemId
  Price

TransactionAggregation:
  ItemId
  TransactionCount
  TotalRevenue
  AverageRevenue // Redundant really, as it's just total revenue / transaction count
```

I don't know where page views fits into that model, if at all.

Comment: hahah wow you made it so simple as that... I had no idea it can be done this easily.. hold on I'll try this code :)

Comment: the average function takes the ItemPrice and divides it by the  pr.Count() parameter ( which in this case is the amount of times that ItemID repeats itself in #1 list). Am I correct?

Comment: @User987: Well, it will do that computation internally, and not by calling `Count()`, but yes, that's basically right.

Comment: amazing! Love how the LINQ simplifies life when using C#... I've accepted ur answer :) Edit: it says I can accept it in 3 mintes , so I'll have to wait